How to make JioCinema HomePage like ImageSlider/ViewPager in Android App? Added video link/pic for better understanding
Please look into this video:
https://jmp.sh/s/CnRVVwdUbpCtlI2yNFVS
I'm interested in creating something similar. Any insights or advice would be appreciated.
For those who prefer not to watch the video, here's an image reference

Question:
How can we reduce the size of the first page and increase the size of the next/previous page during the transition, until it fully switches to the next/previous one?
I think, I have to use viewpager for this, but I couldn't understand how!

Approach 1: You can try using android android Transitions to achieve this.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/transitions
Approach 2: Redraw the layout with new layout params for the view (this will cause a lot of redraws)
Hope this nudges you in the correct direction.
